# PHP. Define new value

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

I'm absolute nube in PHP, so excuse me beforehand for what you'll see next.

I have a php feedback script, that receives some values from the HTML form, then forms an email message and sends it.

Among these values there are digits (1 or 2), which I want to convert into human-readable text lines. Here is the variable `$text = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['text']));` which is receiving 1 or 2. In email template it looks like `"blah ".$service." blah"` and in final email message it is `"blah 1 blah"`.

So how do I say in PHP something like that:

```
    $text = if ($value = 1) {
        echo "text line #1";
    }
    else if ($value = 2) {
        echo "text line #2";
    };
```

Thank you, and sorry once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a if statement,

```
if($value == 1) {
    $text = 'text line #1';
}
else if($value == 2) {
    $text = 'text line #2';
}
```

Or, if the range will change in the future you can also apply a switch case statement. For example:

```
switch($value) {
    case 1:
        $text = 'text line #1';
    break;

    case 2:
        $text = 'text line #2';
    break;

    case 3:
        $text = 'text line #3';
    break;
}
```

This is easier in maintenance and easier to expand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($value == 1) {
    $text = 'text line #1';
}
else if($value == 2) {
    $text = 'text line #2';
}
```

In PHP, `=` is the assignment operator. `if($value = 1)` will return true if the assignment to `$value` succeeds, whereas you want comparison (`==`), which checks for equality.